# Is there an option to install Python3.8.13 slim version on an RHEL8 based Docker?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-3.8, yum

I want the exact version of Python 3.8.13 to run on my container, but so far when I used the below, it generated a very large Docker image:

```
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y python3.8 python38-pip && yum clean all
```

The command "yum install python3.8" installs 3.8.13 and this is fine, but as mentioned, the end result (with other required elements) is a bit above 2 GB once built. I would like to make the image smaller and I am wondering if I can use a slim or alpine version of Python 3.8.13.

I was trying with the following commands:

```
yum install -y python3.8.13-slim
yum install -y python3.8.13-slim-buster
yum install -y python3.8-slim
```

Did not succeed, yum does not recognize these as valid packages.
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you build your image `FROM python:3.8.13-slim`, and avoid manually installing it yourself?  Are there other things in the Dockerfile potentially making the image large?

Comment: No, it has to be made from a hardened RHEL8 image, so no option to start to build it from "python:3.8.13-slim", Python has to be installed separately. Also, an Nvidia driver (450) and a list of 9 Python packages (via pip requirements file) are installed along with their dependencies. This grows the image quite big, I was wondering if I can do anything more with the Python part to make it as small as it can be.